# create an image gallery website using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I want to develop a website which is partially an ecommerce website . Partially e-commerce because there is no selling of the producs or any payment gateway to be done . 
But there should be a display of all the images ,User registration etc ,just like any other site . As specified iam not supposed to use any CMS . I would like to know if it is feasible to have such a customised website by not using any CMS . Because there are around 150 high quality images to be displayed on the website .

Any sort of advice would be highly helpfull and appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to use free flash carousel, or jquery carousel to have something smoothy for a good presentation.
However, you might need a database depending on what you expect (static or not).

Comment: yes absolutely ,iam going to use mysql .

Comment: it would not be exactly static  . The administrator should be able to upload and remove pics from the admin panel . That level of customization .

Comment: Wouldn't php + mysql = cms? In the past, I have had a go at writing this kind of thing myself, but now I just use a free (php/mysql) gallery package. The one I use is very customizable, both in terms of storing additional data and in terms of how any and all content is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this shouldn't be a problem. Depends if you wish for your site to be static or not? You could easily create a site that can do what you are asking. If you are familiar with Php and Mysqli you shouldn't have a problem.

**This is how I would tackle your problem:**

1- Create a simple $_SESSION  login script (Allowing you Admin to gain access, this will have its own table)

2- Use a Mysqli database table to hold all records of your uploaded images.

3- Write a Php class to handle Logging in and user management (Change Password etc...) and a second class handling CRUD in regards to site Imagery. The Class should/will move images into a stated directory, and will also update the database table effectively.

4- Use write a function for getting all images and set a limit (for example LIMIT 20)

5- Then use Php to paginate your results within your HTML. Create a second function which will retrieve the next 20 results, from the last ones displayed.

I believe this to be the easiest way to do what you want to do.

Comment: By feasibility , i meant would the site take so much load when it comes to displaying the pages with so many images . plus are there any libraries in particular to be used to reduce the load time ?

Comment: The pages shouldn't take long to load, your best bet if you are displaying images in grid form, for example you would want to use some pagination. That way the page doesn't have to load the entirety of the images all at once (You could use either just php/mysql or php/mysql and j'query) To reduce any load time issues you could use something like Memcached, but I wouldn't see you having to use it with what you are doing.